# recipe of not giving expected results

Tags: chef-infra

I want to execute a command only if the given directory "/local/update/" doesn't exist

My recipe code is below

```
execute 'test' do
   command "some command here"
   not_if { ::File.directory?("/local/update/") }
end
```

also tried

```
not_if { ::File.exist?("/local/update/") }
```

Even when the directory is present it still runs the command.
I have checked in client.log and this step is not skipped

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Which version of Chef are you running? Also, does `not_if 'ls /local/update/'` work?

Comment: @seshadri_c I have not tried not_if  ```'ls /local/update/'``` earlier ,but tried now.Its working.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer as there is a better (in-built) way to make the `execute` resource idempotent. Instead of skipping it using `not_if`, we can use the `creates` property. From the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/):

> `creates`
>
> Ruby Type: String
>
> Prevent a command from creating a file when that file already exists.

Example:

```rb
execute 'test' do
   command "some command here"
   creates '/local/update/'
end
```

With this implementation, the `command` will run if the `/local/update/` path does not exist. Otherwise it will report as "up to date":

```
* execute[test] action run (up to date)
```

Comment: this is a bit unintuitive solution - you're essentially "saying" you would create something but you're really not, you're just using the construct to bypass execution if the path already exits

Comment: Yes and that's the requirement of the question. First time command ran, it created some path. Next time command need/should not run, so we say this command "creates" "xyz" path, so if it exists, don't run. Consider the command as `mkdir /local/update`.